# Rendering Problems Failed to convert @drawable/1 into a drawable. I am using file name in numbers

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/2" />
```

here i am using the image file name in number that is [0,1,2,.....], but I am getting same Rendering problem I was unable to solve it. please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have resources that start with a number. If you do a full build, you will get an error like:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /tmp/RuntimePermTutorial/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/2.png: Error: The resource name must start with a letter
```

Please use letters, numbers, and underscores when naming your resources, but they cannot start with a number.